# how to increase session timeout in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I tried following codes to increase session timeout, but no use,

code is:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="60">
</sessionState>
```

Also code at

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Code that runs when a new session is started
Session.Timeout = 15;
}
```

Comment: This should work.  How are you checking that your session is timing out?

Comment: take a loot at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656463/increasing-session-timeout

Answer (score 36):

You can increase the session time-out in asp.net in any one of the following ways

**Using IIS Version 7 :**

1. Open up **IIS**
2. Select your website from the list of sites
3. Click on **Session state** on the right
4. Now enter your session timeout under the cookie settings

OR

**Web.config :**
Open up your web.config file and under the **system.web** section add the following :

```
<sessionState timeout = "20" mode = "InProc" />
```

Replace 20 with whatever number you wish.

OR

**Global.asax file :**
Under the **Session_Start** method, set the **timeout** property of the session to the required value like this

```
Session.Timeout = "20";
```

**Note :** If you are setting a session timeout in both IIS as well as web.config, then the one in IIS will override the one in web.config

Hope this helps!

Comment: You forgot to close the sessionState tag in your example. You should write: <sessionState timeout = "20" mode = "InProc" />

Comment: Hey thanks for informing me on that, will update my answer with it ! much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, under IIS 7, setting the session one place sets it in the other. So if you set it in IIS, it will update the Web.config automatically, and vice versa.

Comment: How can we do this in code (for example if there is a "Remember me" checkbox on login)?

Comment: 20 is for minutes, hours or days?

Comment: @MuhammadAwais - its minutes.

Comment: @Worthy7 - This link should be helpful --> http://forums.asp.net/t/1303629.aspx?How+to+implement+remember+me+fucctionality+of+login+page+in+asp+net

Comment: If you define in web.config: <sessionState timeout = "20" mode = "InProc" />

Comment: If you define in web.config: 
`<sessionState timeout = "20" />`
 is redundant write again in code: `Session.Timeout = 20`
Additionally for me (I needed 60 mins session duration), was necessary setup App Pool. Go to IIS admin, then App Pool, then Advanced settings, then into Process Model, set "Idle time-out (minutes)" to 60. If your website use authentication, cookie authentication expiration must be configured at least with double duration of session, if you update expiration in each request, take care of set Secure property according to setting in FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using forms authentication then the default value of session timeout is 30min.Try this code to increase session timeout.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="70"/>
  </authentication>
  <sessionstate timeout="80"/>
</system.web>
```

I think the code help you.

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me the difference between the two timeout values? i.e. `Forms` timeout & `Sessionstate` timeout

Comment: @NitinSawant - here is an existing answer on stackoverflow to your query --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812994/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-sessionstate-timeout

Answer (score 2):

simply,go WebConfig,then set it,

```
        <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="70"/>
  </authentication>
  <sessionState timeout="80"/>
</system.web>
```

It works for me, copy it to your web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add my final solution. After reading that setting it in the config was "incorrect".

```
            if (model.RememberMe)
            {
                var ASPCookie = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
                ASPCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
                Response.SetCookie(ASPCookie);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="30" mode="InProc"/>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="AppRootForms" loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
<system.webServer>
     <!--<max limit for storing session />-->
    <asp>
         <session allowSessionState="true" max="100000" timeout="00:30:00" />
    </asp>
</system.webServer>
```