# How to extend the session time when session empty in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

I need to extend the session timeout in MVC to maintain the user session. Tried to make session extend on `Session_End` in global.asax but it didn't worked.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990619/how-to-increase-session-timeout-in-asp-net ?

Comment: is it ok if extend from javascipt/jquery?

Comment: you mean, if your session time out 20 Min and 15 Min elapse and after that session time out again reset to 20 Min right?

Comment: yes @SandipPatel. ok for javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **call controller method at specific time interval** as per your requirement to reset session timeout by this way your application got focused on some time interval.

Place your JQuery code in layout

**JQuery:**

```
var RefreshSessionInterval;

$(document).ready(function () {        
      clearInterval(RefreshSessionInterval);
      RefreshSessionInterval = setInterval("RefreshSession()", 30000);  // change your interval time as per requirement     
});

function RefreshSession() {
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("RefreshSession", "YourControllerName")',           
            success: function (data) {               
            },
            error: function () {
            }
       }); 
}
```

**Controller:**

```
Public void RefreshSession()
{
    //your session reset from this line, as i know you don't have to write any code here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This In Your Web.config file,
    change the timeout given ,
    now the timeout is set to 60 minutes

```
<configuration>
 ...
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" />
</system.web>
 ...
</configuration>
```