# how to increase Session time out for ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis-7

I have asp .net application , 
I am struggling to increase the session timeout but so far still 20 Minutes : 
I have changed from two location :
1- in IIS (click on the application directory in iis --> in ASP section --> in services   --> in session properties -- > the time-out i set 9:00:00 (9 hours ) and also the "enable session state" is set to true 
2- in web config I add this :
`<sessionState timeout="540" mode = "InProc"></sessionState>`
however still the session 20 minutes 
please help 
thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your are having issues with the ASP.NET Session timeout or maybe it's the Forms Authentication cookie that expires after 20 minutes? Remember that sessions and forms authentication cookies are 2 completely different notions in ASP.NET which shouldn't be confused. You could very well have set your session timeout to be 9 hours but if your authentication cookie expires after 20 minutes, the user will be logged out (but will continue having access to the session variables unless you have cleared them).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to increase session timeout in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990619/how-to-increase-session-timeout-in-asp-net)