# how to disable login after specific period of time

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to disable a login of a particular user after a particular period of time.
it can even called as user credentials or subscription mode.If the subscription period is done user should not login. is there any code in c# asp.net code for this.kindly please help me.
thank you

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990619/how-to-increase-session-timeout-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  am  not able to recall as of now,  But there is a notification based nuget package available in VS .  It works on observer pattern and keep pinging your application.

if the time expires , it will notify the user and will help you to log off  as well .

Answer (score 0):

You need a table to keep the users and the appropriate time for each user and has to be communicate with this table for each login.